# An equivalent condition to show a family of holomorphic functions is normal

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity, normal-families

This is a problem from Complex analysis - Conway

Show that for a set $F \subset H(G)$, the followings are equivalent

(1) $F$ is normal family

(2) For every $\epsilon >0$, there is a number $c>0$ such that $\{\ cf : f \in F \}\ \subset B(0;\epsilon)$. ($B(0;\epsilon)$ is the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ with center at $0$ in $H(G)$)

I am struggling with both the sides. I have the following progress

Let $F$ be a normal family. Given $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta >0$ and $K\subset G$, compact s.t

$$sup\{\ |f(z)||z\in K \}\ \implies f\in B(0;\epsilon) \hspace{2 cm} ..... (1)$$

Since $F$ is a normal family, for the above $\delta >0$ and $K \subset G$, compact we have $f_{1}, f_{2},... f_{n} \in F$ such that given any $f\in F$, there is a $f_{i} (1\leq i \leq n)$ such that 
$$sup \{\ |f(z)-f_{i}(z)| |z\in K \}\ < \delta  \hspace{3 cm} ..... (2)$$

So from (1) and (2), what we have is  for each $f\in F$ , there is a $f_{i}(1\leq i \leq n)$ such that $f-f_{i} \in B(0;\epsilon)$.

I am lost after this. I don't know how to find this $"c"$. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you show that if $f_n$ is a bounded sequence of holomorphic (analytic) functions on $|z| < 2$, then there is a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ converging uniformly (to an analytic function) on $|z| \le 1$ (it follows from the compactness and the Cauchy integral formula)

Comment: Even if I show, what after that?

Comment: What do you mean "after that" ? There is nothing else to prove : every locally bounded family has a subsequence converging locally uniformly, and conversely.